# extracting url response values in iOS

Tags: ios, webview

In my application I am trying to load a particular url on web view.The url is getting loaded properly. When the transaction fails the absolute url which is returned in response from the web view is `https://abc.xxx.com/check/resources/load.html#failed` And when it is successful the absolute url which is returned is 
`https://abc.xxx.com/check/resources/load.html#SUCCESSFUL:1048:7771.00:INR:1397312651798`

I am having a problem in fetching the response like if I get a successful tag how do I fetch the string SUCCESSFUL from response. I want to perform a conditional check if the response is successful or failed.

Comment: You'll need to post some code of what you've tried already

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a delegate on the [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/).

Then using the [`UIWebViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate) method [`-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a)

When creating the web view:

`webView.delegate = self;`

Then add the delegate method in the view controller that the web view is contained in.

`-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
   {
      NSURL *url = request.URL;
      if ([url.host isEqualToString:@"abc.xxx.com"]) {
         NSString *fragment = url.fragment;
         // Do something with the fragment which is the bit after the #
         // Return NO if you don't want to load the URL
      }
      return YES;
   }`